# Ctrl+[ not working in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, shortcuts

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (trace precedents) is not working on my new laptop. I am using Excel 2013. Can anyone explain how to set it to work?

Answer (score 1):

According to [KeyRocket](http://www.veodin.com/excel-2013-shortcuts/), use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to trace precedents in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Save the file as 'Excel 97-2003 Workbook. Then try Ctrl+[. If worked, then save the file as 'Excel Workbook'.